# how to specify in Treeview widget which values will be placed in a column?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview

can someone help me how to move this row to the left?

the word "twitter" should be in [Account Name] column and so on...

and also, the value in [description] column is missing. But I stored it properly in List.

[image]

Comment: You need to show your code, a [mre].

Comment: Ok. my code is too long (239 lines).    i'll put it on gdrive.

Comment: We don't need the full code, just a strip down version that can be executed and reproduce the issue.

Comment: Guess that column `Account Name` is the tree column ('#0'), and inserting data into the treeview using `values` option does not include this column.

Comment: Yes. it is (#0) in the tree column

Comment: Then you can use `tree.insert('', 'end', text=row[0], values=row[1:])` if `row` is the values to be inserted.

Comment: Thank you so much! You save my life xD    @acw1668